How can I use non default port types in Jack?
What I'm running
I'm trying to create a non-default-type port in jack (meaning not audio and not midi), but am unclear if this is even really possible, as I haven't found any examples or discussion around it, although based on the docs it should be supported.
I'm running the following code:
    jack_port_t *ret1 = jack_port_register(client, "testAudio", JACK_DEFAULT_AUDIO_TYPE, JackPortIsOutput, 0);
    jack_port_t *ret2 = jack_port_register(client, "hw2p", "my port type", JackPortIsInput, 256);

Result
ret1 returns a valid port, but ret2 is nullptr.
Intended Result
They should be both valid ports (non-null).
Relevant docs
The Jack API includes the following in its description of the jack_port_register function:
jack_port_t* jack_port_register (   jack_client_t *     client,
const char *    port_name,
const char *    port_type,
unsigned long   flags,
unsigned long   buffer_size 
)

"...All ports have a type, which may be any non-NULL and non-zero length string, passed as an argument. Some port types are built into the JACK API, like JACK_DEFAULT_AUDIO_TYPE or JACK_DEFAULT_MIDI_TYPE"
And it states the following for the buffer_size parameter of that function:
"must be non-zero if this is not a built-in port_type. Otherwise, it is ignored."
Any help greatly appreciated!
Source: https://jackaudio.org/api/group__PortFunctions.html

If you check the website of the product, you will find its description (emphasis mine) :

JACK Audio Connection Kit (or JACK) is a professional sound server API
and pair of daemon implementations to provide real-time, low-latency
connections for both audio and MIDI data between applications.

The product is clearly aimed at audio data.
If you download and check the source code, you can see it's clearly aimed at processing audio, with concepts such has bit depth, channels, sampling frequency, etc...
You talk about "non-standard" port, but there's no such thing.
You either have an audio port, a MIDI port, a serial port, an USB port, ... because a port is not just a variable, but a physical connector defining which wire connect to which wire, and how the end devices speak together (the communication protocol).
Depending of the protocol you try to implement, there's probably an open-source alternative to JACK.
